# App does not use Sqlite, but receives Sqlite error

Tags: android, sqlite

I received an "SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full" exception in my user report.

my app does not use Sqlite. Would like some advice on where this sqlite error originate from.

I used the following dependencies  for my app.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.innahema:collections-query:0.2.9'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1' 
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0' 
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
```

any advice is appreciated.

The log is as follows

```
Exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full (code 13)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId (SQLiteConnection.java)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId (SQLiteConnection.java:786)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId (SQLiteSession.java:788)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert (SQLiteStatement.java:86)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict (SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
blw.a (blw.java:70)
bmn.run (bmn.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:848)
```

The following are the app's permission. It will read from and write image files to external storage as well as use the camera to take pictures. The app does not access other resources like contacts, SMS and Calendar.

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
twitch.angelandroidapps.tracerlightbox.permission.C2D_MESSAGE

Comment: please post full error log

Comment: Is your app proguarded? May be you try to use a dependency that has an SQL database in it. If it isn't proguarded the error is related to one of the dependencies that use proguard.

Comment: `my app does not use Sqlite` Maybe not **directly**. But you may be using it **indirectly** (i.e.: by using the **contacts**, **SMS**s, the **calendar** or what not).

Comment: are you using any other data base or this method in your code getExistingDocument().find in path

Comment: also check runtime permissions

Comment: You need to deobfuscate your stacktrace if your app is using Proguard. Because the only usefull thing is in  `blw.a (blw.java:70)
bmn.run (bmn.java:32)` lines

Comment: Is there any WRITE_PERMISSION ?

Answer (score 0):

run app in debug mode and turn on

> Run in Debug | View Breakpoints | Exception Breakpoints

[image]

then you will see stack trace on needed exception and library that use sqlite